# Visual Studio - .NET Framework 4.6.1 Issue for users with Windows 8.1 or Older

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

**tl;dr - It just opens, shows/executes nothing and closes on anything older than Windows 10 as it works perfectly fine on Windows 10.**

Test it for yourself: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/krxhh1515u7wmfn/PRAGMA.exe?dl=1

**Working on Windows 10:**
[image: 1]

**Not Working on anything Older then Windows 10:**

(This shows if I make the Startup Form something that isn't the Form containing Methods/Functions new in 4.6.1 and then call the Form containing the new Methods/Functions using {MainForm}.Show())
[image: 2]
(Windows 8.1 Too: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jfxrk.png)

I have a Program made in **VB.NET** and it uses **.NET Framework 4.6.1** as I thought it would have the least issues but I was wrong, If anyone on **Windows 7/8/8.1** tries to run my Application nothing loads due to it using some functions only on .NET Framework 4.6.1.

I can confirm it is because of using .NET Framework 4.6.1 as if I load a form in .NET Framework 4.6.1 with no functions new in .NET Framework 4.6.1 then it loads fine, But if I load a Form with a function like **.ToUnixTimeInMilliseconds()** it loads, shows and executes nothing then closes. I know it at least loads *something* as when I open it you can see the Window Focus go out of lets say Windows Explorer to the just Opened app but nothing at all Executes or shows it just eventually closes (I assume) as I cannot find any related process in Task Manager.

This shouldn't be an issue, Windows 7/8/8.1 can install .NET Framework 4.6.1 so why doesn't it load on Windows 7/8/8.1?

Has anyone even realized this issue as I googled for ages and nothing close to being related comes up. Am I missing something Obvious?

Comment: It's not clear from your message as to whether or not the users of your application actually do have .NET 4.6.1 installed? Yes Windows 7 and Windows 8 can install .NET 4.6.1 but that doesn't mean it's automatically installed already.

Comment: @Dmitry I had another user on TeamViewer and we both could confirm that .NET Framework 4.6.1 was installed as I tried running the Web Installer and it said ".NET Framework 4.6.1 or a newer version is already installed on this system." I also had 2 other users who Test my Project tell me that it also doesn't load for them and they also have it installed.

Comment: Have you checked the Windows event log to see what's been logged there for your program? If it crashed, then some call stack info can be there for you to analyze. A crash dump if collected properly can give you more hints.

Comment: @LexLi No as I havent heard of such a thing but when I load a different Startup Form and call the main one using .Show it shows a Error Box with the following code: http://pastebin.com/raw/9cc2ze5S You can see in it that it calls the UpdateForm and it opens fine, It then does a MainForm.Show() call but then eventually while opening it gives an error due to that form having a Function that only came in 4.6.1

Comment: @ShinyMK this exception shows a typical coding issue of wrong type cast. I don't think it is relevant but you might fix it and then try again.

Comment: @LexLi Ok, But what line e.t.c cause I dont even know what a Cast is I know theres some kind of TypeCast() function but I never used it and the App works fine on Windows 10 so...

Comment: A try-catch block around all of `static void main()` or `Sub Main` is your friend.

Comment: @BenVoigt I have heard people talk about Sub Main a lot but I dont know what people mean by it as I cant seem to find the file containing it anywhere.

Comment: As you guys can see it works full fine on Windows 10 no errors AT ALL in the Debugging Window bit bottom left or the Exception Window: https://i.gyazo.com/40b20a6bfd53cf31d69ab4e07a7fb4f5.gif

Comment: @ShinyMK: In C# WinForms, there's usually a `Program.cs` created by the new project wizard that has `static void main()` which creates your main form and then calls `Application.Run`.  Does VB.NET have something like that?  (And then WPF works different too, it starts from App.xaml)

Comment: Anyway, you have a useful stack trace in that pastebin.  Show the code for `PRAGMA.UpdateCheck.CheckForUpdate()` and maybe we can spot the problem

Comment: @BenVoigt Well thats actually an old Stack Trace I got from a User. Theres no longer any UpdateCheck form e.t.c its now executed on Form Load from the Main Forms .Load method. But its only showing that in the Stack Trace because I had Pragma.Show() (Which is the man form). Do you yourself have Windows 10? If not you yourself could open it and get a more up to date Stack Trace as im on Windows 10 D:

Comment: Ok Update - I may have found out why this is happening. It seems that its happening because VLC is not installed not that its not on Windows 10 ... I cant confirm this is why its happening but it sure looks that way testing it now.

Comment: @Dmitry : The application would not run at all if .NET 4.6.1 wasn't installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you reference an ActiveX component which is not installed `0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)`.

```
Exception object: 02499020
Exception type:   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
Message:          Klasse nicht registriert (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))
InnerException:   <none>
StackTrace (generated):
    SP       IP       Function
    00000000 00000001 System_Windows_Forms_ni!System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CoCreateInstance(System.Guid ByRef, System.Object, Int32, System.Guid ByRef)+0x2
    0037E2A0 6B2B0992 System_Windows_Forms_ni!System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateWithLicense(System.String, System.Guid)+0xc2
    0037E2EC 6B2B0A86 System_Windows_Forms_ni!System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstanceCore(System.Guid)+0x2e
    0037E320 6B2B0A45 System_Windows_Forms_ni!System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstance()+0x99
    0037E348 6B2B1D63 System_Windows_Forms_ni!System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.GetOcxCreate()+0x17
    0037E354 6B2AEE74 System_Windows_Forms_ni!System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.TransitionUpTo(Int32)+0xc0
    0037E3A0 6B2AE08A System_Windows_Forms_ni!System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateHandle()+0x2a
    0037E3C0 6ACDD215 System_Windows_Forms_ni!System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean)+0x75
    0037E3FC 6ACDD2E8 System_Windows_Forms_ni!System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean)+0x148
    0037E438 6B2AC785 System_Windows_Forms_ni!System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.EndInit()+0x2d
    0037E444 001E50D2 PRAGMA!PRAGMA.Pragma.InitializeComponent()+0x3a62
    0037EC70 001E0F58 PRAGMA!PRAGMA.Pragma..ctor()+0x1b0
```

Comment: Yep just confirmed myself that is because of ActiveX VLC if VLC Itself isnt installed on the PC then it gives this error. How can I like cache/copy the files needed for the activex VLC and then put it inside the .exe so that if they dont have VLC installed then it would still work? (I need the files from vlc 2.2.1 not the latest version 2.2.2 as its actually more buggy believe it or not).

Comment: try to embedd it as resource, during run, extract the resource and register the dll/ocx after you did this, call InitializeComponent() in constructor.

Comment: Im trying to do that but for some reason when I uninstalled 2.2.2 and installed 2.2.1 and when i try to Choose Items > VLC > Drag and Drop its saying it couldnt import right :/

Comment: add the file to your project and configure VS to copy the dll into the output folder. run the regsvr32.exe command before InitializeComponent() to register the dll.

Comment: No idea how to do that but either way I just updated back to 2.2.2 as drag and drop works on it and i set it to "Embed Interop Types" on both AxAXVLC and AXVLC and I get this when I try to Build: https://i.gyazo.com/276367b8a40f4befed034a5e45df9117.png

Comment: So I guess Embeding the Interop isnt gonna work any other way?

Comment: I have no other idea. Ask this in a new question (now you know why it fails) and tag it correctly. Maybe someone else has more experience with ActiveX

Comment: Yh ill do that, This answer is a solution technically so marked as answer.

Comment: Yo need more help related on this Question, How can I make a Try Catch so that if this error happens I can execute some code like maybe download files and put them places ETC?

Comment: add try catch around InitializeComponent() in constructor

Comment: That kind of works, Like it works and detects but the WPF Designer will fail to function if I have it inside the Sub but if I put it outside of it it gives me an error saying it cannoy be outside of a method body or something D:

Comment: Also im using VB.NET not C# if that makes a difference

Comment: I never used VB so I can't help here.